# SQL Stored Procedure to join three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

I am currently trying to write a stored procedure in SQL that will pull data from three tables.

```
PerformOrder - AppointmentID, PatientID, ImagingOrderID
ImagingOrder - ImagingOrderID, PatientID, PhysicianID
ImagingEquipment - EquipmentID
```

PerformOrder connects to imagingorder and imagingequipment but imagingorder and imagingequipment do not connect to each other

I want appointmentID, patieintID, imagingorderID, physicianID, and equipmentID to be shown when i run the query.

I am completely new to SQL and very lost. Any help would be appreciated!

---

EDIT:

This is my stored procedure but i get an error message of

"Procedure or function 'up_AppointmentInvoice2' expects parameter '@PatientID', which was not supplied." when i try to execute it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE up_AppointmentInvoice2


--Receive Parameters 
@PatientID int,
@AppointmentID int,
@EquipmentTypeID int,
@ImagingOrderID int,
@PhysicianID int


AS


--Generate the list
SELECT i.PatientID, p.AppointmentID, p. EquipmentID, i.ImagingOrderID, i.PhysicianID
FROM ImagingOrder i INNER JOIN PerformOrder p
  ON i.ImagingOrderID = p.ImagingOrderID
```

Comment: why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: @ysth so that i can retrieve this data later on without having to type it all out again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have appointmentID, patieintID, imagingorderID and  physicianID from joining table PerformOrder and ImagingOrder as below. But there is no link between ImagingEquipment and other two table.

```
select p.appointmentID, i.patieintID, i.imagingorderID, i.physicianID, p.EquipmentID
from PerformOrder p
inner join ImagingOrder i on i.ImagingOrderID=p.ImagingOrderID
```

Comment: Oh sorry! I accidentally left it out PerformOrder also has EquipmentID so there is a link. How would i do it then?

Comment: I have changed my answer. You can have EquipmentID from PerformOrder table. No need to join ImagingEquipment at all

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! One more question, if you do not mind, when i run the stored procedure, it gives me this error "Procedure or function 'up_AppointmentInvoice' expects parameter '@PatientID', which was not supplied." do you know why?

Comment: Can you please share the procedure you wrote?

Comment: i have included it in my original post

Comment: Since you are not using any parameters in your query you need to to have those in procedure. you can remove `@PatientID int,
@AppointmentID int,
@EquipmentTypeID int,
@ImagingOrderID int,
@PhysicianID int`